# How to get Sequence number in ninjaforms

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I am trying to insert ninja forms entries in my mysql database. I know that ninjaforms provides a  merge called {submission:sequence}. How can i use this in my functions inside functions.php where i defined a custom action for storing forms data in mysql database. Do you know what the variable is called or is there any global_variable defined by ninja forms that holds the sequence value ?